# How to get the specific row for another view in CI 3

Tags: php, view, pagination, codeigniter-3

I have a table with values from the database like this:

| name | company | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| charles | jollibee | view |
| ultor | lee | view |

I want to be able to get the values of the rows im clicking the view button from to another view for example: if i click the view button of charles'  row, the next view will be able to access charles' different data and display it.

this is my view for the table:

```
<tbody>
   <?php foreach($peoplelist as $row): ?>
       <tr>
           <td> <?php echo $row->col_full_name; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row->col_lcomp_name; ?></td>

           <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('Users/borrowerdetails')?>" role="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">View</button>
           </td>
       </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: How does `Users/borrowerdetails` know which user to display?

Comment: Use: `Users/borrowerdetails/<add user Id here>`,  send the user Id to this URL, and based on the user id get the appropriate details and show.

Comment: users/borrowerdetails just gets the appropriate rows for the table 

how do i add the user id in borrowerdetails?